# Can I conditionally return iterators from different containers from a function?

Tags: boost, stl, c++20

I have two containers `C` and `D`; both storing values of type `T`. I would like to return a "(first, last)-iterator pair" from a function, which depending on a parameter returns `C::begin(), C::end()` or `D::begin(), D::end()`. Is that possible? Is there some kind of "wrapper" for all iterators over `T`'s?

(I know, I could implement some kind of "for_each", but I really need the iterators itself, since I want to pass them further).

Comment: Are `C` and `D` type names, or variable names?  In general, you have to decide what the type that the function will return at compile time. (though you can fudge it somewhat with, say `variant`)

Comment: you might try to use https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/iterator/doc/iterator_facade.html - but still - it will require some kind of PIMPL idiom (virtual functions) under the hood, unless you want to expose possible container types - then use std::variant. Or all containers are of contiguous memory - like vector and array - then use std::span

Answer (score 0):

If they are the same type no problem.  If they are not, you cannot, there is no "base class" for iterators of T.

Now, you can implement a "base class" for iterators of T, and it has been done, but this turns out to be amazingly slow compared to raw iterators.

An object representing a foreach over `T` is both easier to write and will run faster than that.

```
template<class T>
struct foreach_over {
  std::function< void( std::function<bool(T)> )> operation;
  bool knownToBeEmpty = false;

  bool operator()( std::function<bool(T)> f ) const {
    return operation(std::move(f));
  }
  void operator()( std::function<void(T)> f ) const {
    operation([&](T t){ f(std::forward<T>(t)); return true; });
  }

  template<class It, class Sent>
  foreach_over( It begin, Sent end ):
    operation([begin, end](std::function<bool(T)> f) {
      for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        if (!f(*it))
          return false;
      }
      return true;
    }),
    knownToBeEmpty(begin==end)
  {}
};
```

this little package lets you wrap up any two containers into the same foreach operation.

```
std::vector<int> bob;
std::deque<int> alice;

foreach_over<int const&> pick( bool which ) {
  if (which)
    return {bob.begin(), bob.end()};
  else
    return {alice.begin(), alice.end()};
}
```

users simply do:

```
auto foreach = pick(true);
foreach( [](int const& x) {
  std::cout << x << ",";
});
```

the `foreach_over<int const&>` object can be passed along or the like wherever.

Early exit is handled by `return false`, but void-returning lambdas are also accepted.

Comment: std::function makes it slow I guess

Comment: @PiotrNycz The function slows it down,  yes; but for iterators, you have to do std function like overhead like 5 times per element.  With the above, the overhead is 1 per element.  You can make the above more optimal by iterating in batches, and type-erasing the batching, but that gets complex.